# Handling reciprocals of negative square roots in SymPy

Tags: python, math, sympy, symbolic-math, complex-numbers

I am working with a function of the form:

```
import sympy as sm
a,b,x = sm.symbols('a b x')
f = sm.integrate(sm.cos(a*x + 0.5*b*x**2),(x,0,1))
```

[The full integral looks like this in SymPy's formatted output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Khuo3.png).
I don't really know the mathematical theory behind it, but I assume that this is a correct formulation.

However, the problem I'm having occurs in the arguments of the Fresnel S and C functions, where there is a factor of `1/sqrt(b)`. This means that when `b` is negative, the denominator becomes complex so the total argument discontinuously switches sign. The integral itself is always real as the complex terms cancel, but the sign change propagates to the overall value of the integral as well, eg:

```
f.subs([(a,1),(b,1e-9)]).evalf()
# =0.84147
f.subs([(a,1),(b,-1e-9)]).evalf()
# =−0.84147
```

At least for my application, it would make sense that this function is continuous at `b=0`. I am also a bit confused around the ambiguity of this reciprocal square root term, which is seems could be equivalently written: `1/sqrt(b) = sqrt(1)/sqrt(b) = sqrt(1/b)`, which loses the sign change for negative `b`. In fact my current workaround is to rewrite the Fresnel arguments from `1.0*a/(sqrt(pi)*sqrt(b))` to `1.0*a/(sqrt(pi))*sqrt(1/b)` in the SymPy expression.

Additionally, I have tried this in MATLAB's symbolic toolbox, and it seems to give the output I am expecting by default:

```
syms a b x real
f = int(cos(a*x + 0.5*b*x^2),x,0,1)
```

[MATLAB's formatted integral looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mq8Go.png)

Notably, the `1/sqrt(b)` term appears as `sqrt(1/b)` in the numerator of the S and C arguments (sigma1 and sigma4 replacements).

How can I get SymPy to evaluate this function the same way MATLAB does? As mentioned, I have a hacky workaround of manually modifying part of the SymPy string expression, but this is obviously not ideal and probably won't work for more complex expressions I need to derive from it.

Comment: This is a sympy bug. Please report to github: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/new

Comment: To avoid complex numbers you could use a different formula for when b is negative. See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5Bcos%5C%2840%29ax+-+bPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%2Cx%5D and https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5Bcos%5C%2840%29ax+%2B+bPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%5C%2841%29%2Cx%5D (change for b/2)

Comment: @OscarBenjamin thanks for confirming, I have opened an issue: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/25093

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1/sqrt(b) = sqrt(1)/sqrt(b) = sqrt(1/b)` is not true when `b` is negative. Consider `b=-1`: `1/sqrt(-1) = 1/i = i/(i*i) = i/-1 = -i` whereas `sqrt(1/-1) = sqrt(-1) = i`. If you want this replacement to happen I don't think you have any choice but to do the replacement `f.subs(1/sqrt(b), sqrt(1/b))`:

```py
>>> f.subs(1/sqrt(b),sqrt(1/b)).subs([(a,1),(b,-1e-9)]).evalf(2)
0.84
```

Comment: For what it's worth, `f.subs(sqrt(1/b),1/sqrt(b))` also works; and since for `b < 0`, `1/sqrt(b) = -1/sqrt(b)`, and with the parity of Fresnel functions, both substitutions are effectively multiplying `f` by `-1` for negative values of `b`; Mathematica also gives the same form as the second substitution (and evaluates correctly). Still, the issue is with sympy that applies a simplification rule it shouldn't.

Comment: It is not clear to me what SymPy is doing that is wrong: is it reporting the factor of `sqrt(1/b)` when it shouldn't in the integral? If so, it is the integral that is wrong (I suspect) and not a simplification because SymPy will not interchange between `sqrt(1/b)` and 1/sqrt(b)` unless `b` is nonnegative.

Comment: Thanks, this works for now at least, though as mentioned above it seems SymPy's default behaviour is a bug, so hopefully won't be required in the future after a fix.

Comment: So it is the integral that is wrong, not a simplification? Because you refer to simplification as being a problem but you don't have any simplification steps in your question.

Comment: The problem was the integration rule as Oscar detailed on the github issue, I wasn't really sure what the cause was when I asked the question/made the issue, but thought maybe there was some simplification step SymPy was doing internally (I never did any explicit manual simplification).